# How to add month on date in Liquid Language

Tags: liquid

How to add month on Date?  I need to find past date from today by using number of months. Below code is working for 31 days but in real time month must be 31 days/30 days/Leep Year (Feb).

```
{% assign dateminus = 2 | times: 2678400 %}    
{% assign LastRenewalDate = 'now' | date: '%s' | minus: dateminus | date: "%Y-%m-%d" %}
```

Here "2" is number of month, "2678400" is converted 31 days into second.